# If $ \limsup ( a_n ) = L \in \mathbb{R} $, then is $ (a_n) $ bounded from above?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

If $ \limsup ( a_n ) = L \in \mathbb{R} $ ( Meaning the largest partial limit of $ (a_n) $ is a finite number ) then does this mean $ ( a_n) $ is bounded from above?

I had this question in my mind for awhile and I think the answer is no but I couldn't think of a counter-example.

Comment: If it's not bounded from above, isn't there a subsequence that goes to $\infty$?

Comment: How can there be such subsequence that goes to $ \infty $ if the largest partial limit is a $ L \in \mathbb{R} $?

Comment: That's exactly my point.

Comment: $\exists N$ such that $ a_n \le L+1$ for $n \ge N$. Can you derive an upper bound for all $a_n$?

Comment: @MartinR , Yes the upper bound is: $ M = max\{a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{N},L+1\} $. The proof by contradiction introduced below in the answers cleared things for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(a_{n})$ is not bounded from above, then there is a subsequence $(a_{n_{k}})$ such that $a_{n_{k}}\rightarrow\infty$, but then $\limsup a_{n}\geq\lim_{k}a_{n_{k}}=\infty$.

Comment: So we get a contradiction, hence $ ( a_n) $ must be bounded above?

Comment: Yes, that is right.